# Difference with Linux VmRSS and the total commited memory of Java NativeMemoryTraking (NMT)

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I try to monitor the total memory allocated to my Java application (OpenJDK 11.0.4) by the OS (Linux Ubuntu 19.04).

I take two approches:

- Using the VmRSS size from `ps` or `cat /proc/<pid>/status | grep VmRSS`
- Using Java NativeMemoryTracking functionality with the following properties: `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics` and using the Total committed size.

The numbers retrieved from both approaches are always different (sometimes of a few megabytes ... sometimes a lot more).

What I understand is that the VmRSS size reported by the OS is the real memory used by the process but why does Java NTM reports a different value?

If I want to be able to monitor the Resident Set Size of a Java application, should I rely on the OS reported size (VmRSS) of can I use something inside the JVM (like NTM) ? Ideally I want to be able to monitor the RSS size of my Java application from itself ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a surprise that NMT and RSS numbers are different -- the JVM and the OS use different approaches to measure different things.

NMT can report [much less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734359/jvm-is-using-more-memory-than-native-memory-tracking-says-how-do-i-locate-where) memory than the actual usage, or it can also report [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173374/why-does-a-jvm-report-more-committed-memory-than-the-linux-process-resident-set) memory than the process consumes from the OS perspective. I explained the reasons in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438).

Monitoring RSS inside a Java application is simple. You already know about `/proc/<pid>/status`, so why not just read `/proc/self/status` in Java code? (Linux automatically maps `self` to the current process ID). It's even easier to parse [`/proc/self/stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), since all the information is provided there in a single line in a predefined format.

It's also possible to get NMT report from within Java application as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455262/monitoring-java-native-memory/57485835#57485835).